# How do you sign your Firefox extensions?

Tags: firefox, build-automation, certificate, code-signing

I have developed a couple of extensions for Firefox, and am annoyed that it is so hard to get the extension signed.  When an extension isn't signed, it says "Author not verified" when it is installed, and to me that just looks wrong.

I have a simple build script that builds my .xpi file from sources, and I have a licenced copy of PKZip (which according to a number of tutorials is required to build a signed xpi file that Firefox requires), but I haven't found a way to get a free/cheap certificate that actually works or a set of instructions that do the trick.

Since my extensions are free, I don't want to spend $400 on a commercial certificate, but I don't mind spending $50 or so to get it done.  I have both Linux and Windows machines, although my build script currently uses Windows and that would be most convenient to use.

How have you solved this?  What do I need to do to automatically and securely sign my extensions when they are built?

Edit: I appreciate the Google hits, but the steps they provide aren't complete enough on how to actually get a certificate that works.  The feeling I get reminds me of this classic:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used the comodo certificate to sign XPIs. It was the cheapest option at the time.

<strike>I've written a few posts on the [XPI Forma](http://o-regan.org/2007/04/11/firefox-xpi-internal-structure/)t and a howto for [signing](http://o-regan.org/2007/04/23/extension-signing-with-xpisigner/) using a java commandline tool.</strike>

My  tool [XPISigner](http://o-regan.org/xpisigner-secure-your-firefox-extensions/download-xpisigner/) simplifies the process considerably and is integratable into build systems.

I've removed the tool as it no longer works with FF4 or higher. Source is available on http://code.google.com/p/xpisigner/ if anyone feels like fixing.

Comment: This is all really helpful, thanks - great info.  Is the Comodo certificate the "code signing" one that costs around £110 for a year?

Comment: Finally got enough rep to answer you ;)
That's it. I think I got it a bit cheaper last year by confusing the website into letting me buy in in dollars. The exchange rate with euro was quite favorable then.

You may find resellers that offer it cheaper, think i saw some in another answer on here.

Comment: Just FYI, XPISigner has some issues with Firefox 4 and some CAs.

Answer (score 4):

Avoid the GoDaddy codesigning certs as the necessary intermediate CA certificate isn't in Firefox by default.
    C=US,ST=Arizona,L=Scottsdale,O=GoDaddy.com\,Inc.,OU=http://certificates.godaddy.com/repository,CN=Go Daddy Secure Certification Authority,SERIALNUMBER=07969287'

If you sign with it your users will get signing errors with it.

e.g.

```
SIgning could not be verified. -260
```

Comment: This appears to still be a problem. Noted on this page https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Signing_a_XPI which leads to this bug entry https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=321156.

Answer (score 3):

What I found with Google was this: http://www.mercille.org/snippets/xpiSigning.php which states:

> If you don't want a commercial
>   certificate or can't afford one,
>   [Ascertia](http://www.ascertia.com/) can provide you with a free
>   certificate, but turning it into a
>   code signing certificate requires some
>   extra work, which I have detailed on
>   [another page](http://www.mercille.org/snippets/xpiSigningFreeCA.php).

I can't say that I've tried it.
And on http://developer.mozilla.org/en/Signing_a_XPI it says:

> The cheapest universally supported
>   (Mozilla, Java, Microsoft) certificate
>   seems to be the Comodo Instant-SSL
>   offering. You can get a free
>   certificate for open-source developers
>   from Unizeto Certum, but their root
>   certificate is only present in Mozilla
>   Firefox and Opera (not Java or
>   Microsoft).

Comment: Unfortunately it's not clear *which* certificate on Ascertia to get, and the "another page" is mostly blank at the moment.  I'd like something a little more specific please :)

Comment: Yes, I've looked at the second page too - it's why I bought PKZip.  How exactly do I get the right kind of certificate from Unizeto?  What is the URL to get it?

Comment: Yeah I tried to follow up on this too, and I could not figure out step 2 either.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, XPI signing is unfortunately quite untrivial. I would advise searching/posting to the mozilla newsgroups (dev-extensions, project owners @ mozdev, irc.mozilla.org) and also trying to get in touch with the people who got it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Tucows sells Comodo code signing certificates for $75 per year, that's as cheap as it goes from what I can tell (https://author.tucows.com/, "Code Signing Certificates" section). That's still too much money for me to spend so I didn't try how it works. Not that I can try, from what I can tell you need to be a registered organization to buy a Comodo certificate.

As to Ascertia, getting a certificate is easy enough (http://www.ascertia.com/onlineCA/Issuer/CerIssue.aspx) - but such a certificate is as worthless as a self-issued certificate because you would need to import their root certificate before seeing an effect.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an Open Source project, you can get a free code signing certificate from Unizeto.

The steps to get the certificate itself are described in detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18959881/217357).

Once you have the certificate, do the following:

- get the private key from your browser (e.g. download it as .p12 from your keychain - do not set a password) and convert it into PEM format via `openssl pkcs12 -in key.p12 -nodes -out private.key -nocerts`
- Open your .pem file that you downloaded from Unicert, add your private key beneath it, and the `Public Key of Certum Level III CA` from [here](https://www.certum.eu/certum/cert,expertise_root_certificates.xml#CLIIICA) beneath the private key, so it looks like this:

  `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
  [your certificate from Certum]
  -----END CERTIFICATE-----
  -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
  [the private key you just converted from the .p12 file from your keychain]
  -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
  -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
  [the Certum Level III CA public key you just downloaded]
  -----END CERTIFICATE-----`
- Save this file as `cert_with_key_and_ca.pem`
- Install [xpisign.py](https://github.com/nmaier/xpisign.py) with `pip install https://github.com/nmaier/xpisign.py/zipball/master`
- Run `xpisign -k cert_with_key_and_ca.pem unsigned.xpi signed.xpi`
- Drag & Drop the `signed.xpi` into Firefox and you should see the author name where before there was a *(Author not verified)* message next to the extension name.