# Self Code Signing and Showing Publisher

Tags: code-signing, uac, publisher

I've come across information about showing the publisher in the UAC window and that it requires a publishing certificate. I've made a test one ([Ripped off this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482476/code-signing-certificate)) and signed my EXE with it, and see the signature in the properties of the file. But when running as Admin it still says "Unknown Publisher" (and is yellow). Is this normal? We're going to buy a certificate anyway soon, but I want to know this information as I'm doing it so we don't blow the cash and still having it say "Unknown".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it definitely does work.

**Before digitally signing:**

[image]

**After digitally signing:**

[image]

Yes, it means you'll have to spend $200 a year for a digital signing certificate from someplace. It's a scam. i know.

But you can sleep easy.