# Code signing required for custom windows app?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I've build a small app using Visual Studio 2019. It needs to run on a few machines running Windows 7 and 10. Is it mandatory to code sign the app? Or can the app be copied to other machines and run without code signing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not mandatory. You can copy files as you want. Signing code is only for security and legal purposes. To provide trusted apps in business environment. So it depends of the strategy of your domain.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ieinternals/2011/03/22/everything-you-need-to-know-about-authenticode-code-signing/

https://learn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/ide/how-to-sign-application-and-deployment-manifests

[Validating a Code Signing Certificate on a Windows Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52067029/validating-a-code-signing-certificate-on-a-windows-application?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[Code signing certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482476/code-signing-certificate)