# How can I sign an ActiveX control cab file with a code signing certificate in Google Chrome and IE, not from a certificate authority?

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome, activex, certificate, cab

I am trying to sign and certificate a .cab file packaging .dll and .ocx files on Google Chrome and Internet Explorer 8.0.

In order to find out how to do, I've consulted the [MSDN libary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa231196%28VS.60%29.aspx): it says, "You provide a digital signature by purchasing a certificate from a certificate authority. A certificate authority is a company that validates your identity and issues a certificate to you.".

But I know that it needs to pay to purchase a certificate from a certificate authority, right?

If then, I don't want it. As you know, I'd like a free one and I am not in a condition for purchasing it.

If is there anyone who knows how to do it not from a certificate authority, but only using own root certificate, please inform me..

Answer (score 1):

You pay for the privilege of being able to side code. It's fundamental to their concept of "certifying" you as being trustworthy.

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1177552/code-signing-certificate-for-open-source-projects) is probably as close is you're going to get, where people are looking for certificates for open source projects.