# Is there still a possibility for free code signing certificates in 2018?

Tags: certificate, code-signing, code-signing-certificate

So I'm working on a project that will be open-sourced later.
But when I release my executables with my project, I don't want that each user gets a message that my app is from an *unidentified developer*.

I also don't have the money(I'm 13, so I don't even have a credit card) to buy such a code signing certificate.

And I know that there are a few simular questions about this but the best question I found was this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1177552/code-signing-certificate-for-open-source-projects).
And it was asked more than 9 years ago!

So what I'm basically asking is:"Is it still possible in 2018 to get a **free** opensource code signing certificate?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most basic way would be to generate a certificate yourself and sign with that, which is known as self-signing. In order for your self-generated certificate to be widely trusted, you would have to somehow get it to be signed by some well-known entity. You might try lurking around your local open source festivals/meetups and try and meet respected people and get them to sign your keys and whatnot. This, as you might imagine, is a large investment of time, but it might be worth it in more ways than one.

Or you can get a certificate authority to generate and sign the cert for you, colloquially known as buying the certificate. This usually costs a lot, but is very quick and easy.

There is one other option I know of, and that is [CAcert](https://cacert.org). This is a community-driven free CA, wherein you get rated by other users instead of being verified centrally.

It might be slightly more hassle to the end-user than the expensive certs, and you may have to add CAcert as a trusted authority on the target system. But it's still a lot less than self-signing.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be "verified" you have to purchase a certificate and give buckets of money for the "verification". You can also self-sign your executable using a self-generated certificate but then you would have to install it to the clients' PCs, and it is hard, not to mention the UAC's with "unverified" during installation.

---

Here is a way to bypass the "unverified" prompt in Windows.

Starting the executable with admin right on Python3: [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shellexecutea) is the ctypes function's docs

```py
import ctypes
import sys
ctypes.windll.shell32.ShellExecuteW(None, "runas", "cmd /k"+sys.executable, None, None, 1)
```

Now they will see something like this(I launched the python interpreter):
[Sorry, reputation deficiency, edit requested](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dw0S.png)