# Signing Extension Mozilla Firefox without upload to AMO

Tags: firefox-addon, certificate, mozilla, signing, code-signing-certificate

I want to sign my add-on but i don't want to upload my add-on to AMO for verifying. What can i do for sign my add-ons with my own certificate?
Can anybody tell me how to sign add-on without upload to AMO?

Comment: This is a good question and does not deserve down votes. I'm not sure of the signing process but there is lots of info at the official firefox addon forums and also mozillazine: http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=2907359&sid=7243938cea105a441e62b6c39fed2fd0 and http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=2907359&sid=7243938cea105a441e62b6c39fed2fd0

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you sign your Firefox extensions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129920/how-do-you-sign-your-firefox-extensions)

Comment: Note that very soon there will be no way to do what you are asking unless you run a custom build of Firefox (all addons will be disabled unless they have been signed by AMO). There's updated info at https://wiki.mozilla.org/Addons/Extension_Signing

Comment: i use custom build of firefox, after i search about it and i cannot find another way to solve this problem. so, i bypass verify extension in my firefox...
so my add-on can work normally with signing or without signing...

thanks for all response...

Comment: This is truly amazing. There is NO way to use a custom extension without sending your proprietary code to Mozilla or forcing your in-house users to go outside of the normal Firefox builds. I'm stunned by that. There is simply no reason to use Firefox any more.